# Android NFC App with BlackBerry 10 support

Tags: android, nfc, blackberry-10

I developed an Android app that writes on NFC Tags. Everything is working fine on Android phones with the following code:

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    [...]
    val nDef = Ndef.get(tag)
    nDef.connect()
    val mimeRecord = NdefRecord.createMime("text/plain", message.toByteArray(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
    nDef.writeNdefMessage(NdefMessage(mimeRecord))
    nDef.close()
    [...]
}
```

So nothing special.

Now one of the users uses a BlackBerry 10 and he can't write to the NFC tag (`writeNdefMessage` is throwing an IOException without a detailed message).

Is there any chance to get this to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS version is your user using? NFC is not supported in 10.2, but is in 10.3 [according to the developer documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupported_api_jellybean_hardware.html)

Comment: It's version 10.3. The native Blackberry app to read/write NFC tags works.

Comment: Off the top of my head I have no idea, but I have a Z10 at home so I'll do a quick spike when I get chance